# my checkbox is not selecting any box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***here is html code**i am trying to fetch checkbox value which are coming from database but my checkbox is not selected any value,only checkbox is showing but not selecting any value....

```
        ng-controller="noduesaccountsmodalcontroller" ng-init="init()">


    <form name="accounts" ng-submit=submit(accounts) novalidate>
<table class="table">

            <thead>
            <tr>
        <th>item</th>
        <th>received</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

        <tbody ng-repeat="emp in nodueaccountassets">      
            <tr>
<td>{{emp}}</td>  <td> <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="emp.selected" value="{{emp.name}}"/></td>

                             </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            {{albumNameArray}}

    <!-- <input type="checkbox" value="{{emp}}"  ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true"{{emp}}><br /> -->                                                    


   <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ACCEPT</button> 
        <button class="btn btn-warning"  ng-click="popup.$rollbackViewValue();">REJECT</button>
```

***js controller code is***

```
           application.controller('noduesaccountsmodalcontroller',function  ($scope,$http,$window,$modal,$filter)                                                                                                                                                     
            $scope.nodueaccountassets=data.list;
        /*alert($scope.nodueaccountassets)*/
                })
            })

$scope.submit=function(form){
    $scope.albumNameArray = [];

angular.forEach($scope.nodueaccountassets,function(emp){
    if (emp.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(emp.name);

     alert(emp.selected);


/*$scope.albumNameArray = $scope.nodueaccountassets.filter(function(emp){
        return emp.selected;

        alert(emp.selected);*/
    })
    /*var emp_data='emp_assets='+$scope.nodueaccountassets+'&accounts_comments='+$scope.empcomments+'&emp_code='+$scope.emplycode;
    alert("data is"+emp_data)

    $http.get(domain+'/insertaccountassets?'+emp_data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    alert('submit successfully');
                })

.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            alert(data);
            })
            alert("error while submitting")
            }       
        $scope.reject=function(form)
        {
$modal.dismiss('reject');
var emp_data='accounts_comments='+$scope.empcomments+'&     emp_code='+$scope.emplycode;
            alert(emp_data)
            $http.get(domain+'/insertaccountassets?'+emp_data)
        }*/
}

});
```

Comment: did you resolve ?

Comment: nop my problem is this project is spring mvc based angular checkbox value is dynamic value but my checkbox not seleted any  box means not seleting even any box and binding of data

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jUcJgkQ3qJaR45L8eKVX?p=preview) out of your provided code and made some tweaks to your HTML and JS code.

Make sure your JSON data has objects in the array so that when you create `.selected` property to the array object and assign as `ng-model` to your checkbox it woks properly

In HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="noduesaccountsmodalcontroller" ng-init="init()">
    <form name="accounts" ng-submit="submit(accounts)" novalidate="">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>item</th>
            <th>received</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="emp in nodueaccountassets">
          <tr>
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="emp.selected" value="{{emp.name}}" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

        {{selectedItems}}


              <!-- <input type="checkbox" value="{{emp}}"  ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true"{{emp}}><br /> -->
      <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ACCEPT</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="popup.$rollbackViewValue();">REJECT</button>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

In JS

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('noduesaccountsmodalcontroller',function($scope){

    $scope.nodueaccountassets = [{'name':'x'},{'name':'a'},
    {'name':'b'},{'name':'c'},{'name':'d'}];

    $scope.init= function(){

    };
    $scope.selectedItems =[];
    $scope.submit = function(acc){
        angular.forEach($scope.nodueaccountassets,function(emp){
            if(emp.selected){
                $scope.selectedItems.push(emp.name);
            }
            });
    };
});
```